# How can I change this into a loop instead of a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

So I have a piece of code like

```
          var barlen = $('#SSWEprogressbar').width(),
              $elems = $('[data-srcurl]'),
                   k = 0,
                   n = $elems.length;
          LoadImage();
          function LoadImage()
          {
              var $elem = $($elems[k]);
              var img = new Image(),
                  url = $elem.attr('data-srcurl');
              $(img).load(function(){
                 $('#SSWEloaderfront').attr('src',url); 
                 $('#SSWEloadprogress').width((k+1)/n*barlen + "px");
                  var srctgt = $elem.attr('data-srctgt');

                  // change url to src attribute or background image of element
                  if ( srctgt == "srcattr" ){ $elem.attr('src',url); }
                  else if ( srctgt == "bgimg" ) { $elem.css('background-image',"url("+url+")"); }   

                  // decide whether to exit the 
                  if ( ++k == n ) { AllyticsSSWEPlayerShow(); }
                  else { LoadImage(); }
              });                 
              img.src = url;
          }
```

and the reason I have it written that way is because `load` callback needs to be called before the stuff in the function can be executed again. If possible, I'd like to change this from a recursive function to a loop, but I don't know how to do that because there's no way to make a `for` or `while` loop "wait" before going on to the next iteration. Or is there?

Comment: You can share your HTML code? :)

Comment: why do you want to do that?  This is (a version of) the usual pattern in JS.

Comment: @AralRoca there's no need to add any HTML here

Comment: @Alnitak, to check the snippet easer only

Comment: @AralRoca it would provide no benefit and serve only to obscure the question

Comment: @Alnitak Okey, true...

Comment: You can't since your code is async

Comment: Can I please note here how incredibly _annoying_ it is for someone to ask a question and then disappear off the site and not pay attention to the question they just asked...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment you can easily resolve your problem, by using `setTimeout(LoadImage, 100);` in the `else` instead of calling the function directly. The 2nd parameter is the delay in ms.

If you understand why `setTimeout(LoadImage, 0);` is not stupid and not the same as calling the function directly then you understood `setTimeout`. It puts the function call in the queue, this means other events like clicks or keys that were pressed can be processed before the function is called again and the screen doesn't freeze. It's also impossible to reach max recursion like this, the depth is 1.

Comment: How does that "solve" any problem - the OP hasn't said what his "problem" is, and in any event (pun not intended) the async nature of the callback already means that the code is only 'pseudo-recursive' and not truly recursive.   The OP's original code also cannot reach "max recursion" because its maximum recursion depth is likewise 1.

Comment: I quote the OP: *"...there's no way to make a for or while loop "wait" before going on to the next iteration. Or is there?"* Yes there is a way, you can use `setTimeout`...

Comment: I read that as the OP wanting to just right a normal `for` loop and do away with recursion for reasons unexplained, and finding himself unable to do so because the for loop does not "wait" for the async function to finish.  I do not believe he is asking for an "artificial" delay between invocations.

Comment: @EdBayiates no, it doesn't.   Each call to `LoadImage` starts with an (almost) new stack because it's called within the `.load` callback, from the event loop.

Comment: @Alnitak took a look at jQuery sources for $.load, you are correct, it is using an async callback, so in effect the code already is not recursive.